# xamarin.ios (monotouch) How to have a help UIImageView appear ABOVE the current view

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am hoping someone can help with this issue that I am having using xamarin.ios. I am trying to present a UIImageView on top of the current view once a button is touched. To illustrate what I mean, see the two screenshots from an app that does exactly what I want. The first shows the 'i' button next to Printers label on the navigationbar, that when touched the second screen as shown in the second screenshot appears.
[image]
[image]
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a "popover".
Xamarin has a recipe for popovers on: http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message